# Iterating over a dictionary of pdf files and their name and create a dictionary and put the name and corresponding text into it

Tags: python, nlp

I wrote the code as follws to extract one single pdf file and put the text into a list. how can I modify the code that it iterates over a dictionary of pdf files and their name and create a dictionary and put the name and corresponding text into it?

```
dic = {
 '0R.pdf':'m1',
 '2R.pdf':'m2',
 '29R.pdf':'m3'}

def readpdffile(pdf_file):
        pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        output = []
        for i in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            output.append(pageObj.extractText())
    
        return output
```